# How to track usage of Hound

Tags: code-search-engine, hound

What are some ways we could monitor Hound, both usage and specific searches? Is there any systems either built in or that can be added as extensions?

We are running Hound on the intranet but we have no visibility of how it's being used and how much usage it gets.

Currently hound is being installed through a puppet pipeline.

**Preliminary ideas:**

1) Add a proxy forwarding endpoint in front of hound to record the "hits" and send it to some DB store. That wouldn't track low level usage of hound (i.e. search queries), just the hits.

2) Somehow enable server logs and parse through the logs? I'm not sure how much info I would get from the logs and the parsing might get involved. Then send this info to some DB store.